# How to delete Â in notepad++

Tags: sql, scripting, notepad++

I have a ksh file which have set of SQL commands (for ex. 35 commands) in it and I used to open it in notepad++. It is executing and returning expected results for the first 5 SQL queries, but for the rest, it is throwing an error.

When I dug into it, in between the SQL commands, there is an extra character like `Â`. How to remove this? I have tried a lot to get rid of it with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: i think that's a carriage return. is that an exported file?

Comment: it is not an exported file, but few sqls i have copied and pasted

Comment: please could you [edit] the question and show part of the file containing those problematic characters?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Hex Editor plugin for NotePad++.  Look at your file as a sequence of byte values rather than an encoded text file.  Find the byte value that corresponds with the Â glyph.

Comment: Can you please share the details how to remove this? I tried many ways!

Comment: Consider a dedicated Hex Editor such as WinHex or HxD rather than NotePad++, which while a great text editor, but isn't a hex editor.  You want to find out which bytes your glyph is composed of by looking in the Hex Editor and then doing a search and replace those byte values rather than the glyph.